# Change default collider bounce direction in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a [Breakout clone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIJ5x.png) in Unity and want to change the direction of the ball based on if the ball hits the left side or the right side of the paddle, as in [the original](https://elgoog.im/breakout/) version of the game. What is the best way of accomplishing this? I tried adding [angled colliders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX8JE.png) to my paddle, but that causes the ball to fall slightly through the paddle before hitting the collider and changing direction.

Comment: The collider can tell you where on the object collider it hit. You could use maths to decide top bottom left or right or whatever suits.

Answer (score 0):

You should have access to the rigid body that you are colliding with, which will tell you the angle you want to bounce at.  Then, you do a late modification of the trajectory ("late" as in after your physics are calculated and applied for velocity).  Something like this should work:

```
Rigidbody2D.velocity = newDirection.normalized * Rigidbody2D.velocity.magnitude;
```